# How to implement continuous deployment of Node.js application to GCP from Jenkins

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any plugin in Jenkins to connect to Google Cloud Platform?

I have installed gcloud SDK plugin and connected to GCP and in gcloud CLI I have written `gcloud app deploy` but not able to deploy successfully.

Comment: Never heard abt it. But find some help from this. May be should help. https://codeforgeek.com/2016/04/continuous-integration-deployment-jenkins-node-js/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.